# Adding a prototype method to an object

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a javascript tutorial on Code Academy. Here's the problem ([link](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/objects-ii/5/2?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661)):

> Add the sayHello method to the Dog class by extending its prototype.
>
> sayHello should print to the console: "Hello this is a [breed] dog",
>   where [breed] is the dog's breed.

Here's my code:

```
function Dog (breed) {
    this.breed = breed;
};

// add the sayHello method to the Dog class 
// so all dogs now can say hello
Dog.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    console.log("Hello this is a %s dog", this.breed);
}


var yourDog = new Dog("golden retriever");
yourDog.sayHello();

var myDog = new Dog("dachshund");
myDog.sayHello();
```

My output:

> Hello this is a golden retriever dog
>
> Hello this is a dachshund dog

And the error I'm getting:

> Oops, try again. It appears that your sayHello method doesn't properly log to the console 'Hello this is a [breed] dog' where [breed] is the breed of the Dog

Is this a problem with CA's code checker or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It doesn't like the method you're using to swap the breed text into the string: `console.log("Hello this is a " + this.breed + " dog");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever method CodeAcademy is using to check your results, it doesn't like how you've processed the text. When I do:

```
console.log("Hello this is a " + this.breed + " dog");
```

It says it's "correct".

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good to me, I think it's an issue with CA.

If you change it to:

`Dog.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    console.log("Hello this is a " + this.breed + " dog");
}`

then CA doesn't complain and says it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using substitution strings in `console.log` is not supported in all versions of Javascript. For example Internet Explorer 9 doesn't support them.

Ref: [MDN: console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log)

Using the older form without a substitution string works:

```
console.log("Hello this is a " + this.breed + " dog");
```